# Navigate fullcalendar months using arrow keys on keyboard

Tags: javascript, navigation

In v3 of fullcalendar i could navigate months using a JavaScript switch statement with the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('next');
```

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
```

I've now migrated to fullCalendar v6.15 and the js switch statement no longer works.

I have tried:

```
calendar.prev();
calendar.next();
```

Which won't work, any suggestions in the right direction appreciated.

#fullcalendar

Comment: I have now found the answwer.  include the onkeydown switch statement in a FullCalendar datesSet function.